# ¿Como actualizar array de archivos en laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto en el cual tengo que guardar varios archivos desde una tabla, ya los puedo guardar el problema es para actualizar o editar no logro hacerlo me sale este error

> "Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::columnize() must be
>   of the type array, integer given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php
>   on line 133"

este el codigo de mi vista

```
   @foreach($archivos as $archivos)
    <tr>
     <td><input type="text" name="nombre_archivo[]" readonly="" value="{{$archivos->nombre_archivo}}"></td>
     <td><input type="file" name="archivo_unidad[]" value="{{$archivos->archivo_unidad}}"></td>
     <td>
      @if(!isset($archivos->archivo_unidad) || $archivos->archivo_unidad == "NULL")
         <label>Sin archivos</label>
      @else
         <a href='{{ url ('download_archivo',$archivos->archivo_unidad)}}' target="_blank">Descargar</a>
      @endif
     </td>
    </tr>
   @endforeach
```

este es mi controlador

```
$nombre = $request->input('nombre_archivo');
$file = $request->file('archivo_unidad');
foreach ($request->input('nombre_archivo') as $key => $value) { 
        if(!isset($file[$key])){
           $archivo = DB::table('archivos_unidades')->where('id_unidad', '=', decrypt($id))->value('archivo_unidad');
        }else{
            $archivo = time()."_".$file[$key]->getClientOriginalName();

            \Storage::disk('archivosunidades')->put($archivo,  \File::get($file[$key]));
        }

        $objModel = ArchivosUnidades::find('id_unidad', decrypt($id));
        $objModel->nombre_archivo = $nombre[$key];
        $objModel->id_unidad = $unidades->id_unidad;
        $objModel->archivo_unidad = $archivo;
        $objModel->save();  }
```

No logro identificar a que se debe el error, recalco que en `ArchivosUnidades::find('id_unidad', decrypt($id));` id_unidad no es la llave primaria de la tabla ArchivosUnidades si no la llave foránea que se relaciona a mi tabla principal llamada unidades

Vista para editar archivos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Vista de la base de datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Creo que en tu query eloquent te falta el "->get();"

```
$archivo = DB::table('archivos_unidades')->where('id_unidad', '=', decrypt($id))->value('archivo_unidad')->get();
```

y aca tambien:

```
$objModel = ArchivosUnidades::find('id_unidad', decrypt($id))->get();
```

Espero eso sea. 
saludos

Comment: Las dos sugerencias son incorrectas, le sugiero revisar la documentación de Laravel, especialmente los métodos `value()` y `find()` del query builder. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries

Answer (score 0):

El método `find()` permite encontrar un modelo por su llave primaria, ese es su único uso, aquí vemos su código:

```
/**
 * Find a model by its primary key.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $id
 * @param  array  $columns
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|static[]|static|null
 */
public function find($id, $columns = ['*'])
{
    if (is_array($id) || $id instanceof Arrayable) {
        return $this->findMany($id, $columns);
    }

    return $this->whereKey($id)->first($columns);
}
```

En ese orden de ideas, estás utilizando el método incorrecto para encontrar un modelo (teniendo en cuenta que no es la llave primaria la que vas a usar como parámetro de búsqueda), yo utilizaría simplemente where:

```
$objModel = ArchivosUnidades::whereIdUnidad(decrypt($id))->first();
```

Comment: Voy a intentar con esta opción no lo he realizado así espero resulte

Comment: no me funciono me arroja el siguiente error: "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::save()" podrías indicarme de donde obtendría el whereidUnidad o que hace?

Comment: Había olvidado agregar el método `first()`, aunque eso ya debería saberlo.

Comment: No entiendo entonces lo que pretende hacer.

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta, yo tengo mi tabla donde quiero editar los archivos, donde dice "sin archivos" pueda el usuario seleccionar uno y se agregue según el nombre de documento y si el usuario quisiera editar alguno de los que ya existen se edite, y solo edita uno se edite ese y no los demás, para eso recurro a recorrer $nombre = $request->input('nombre_archivo'); por que es el input principal que incluye todos los nombres de los documentos, no de los archivos, el la imagen de mysql el numero 3 es el id de la unidad

Comment: Entonces con la opción $objModel = ArchivosUnidades::whereIdUnidad(decrypt($id))->first(); lo que hace es que todos los que contengan 3 en nombre del documento me lo cambia a Factura Adaptacion y con el mismo nombre de archivo para todos